# CiviEvent - Confirmation takes a long time

Tags: civievent

CiviEvent takes a very long time (arounf 120 seconds) to confirm a registration.

From "Confirm Your Registration Information" to "Thank you for registering", the visitor can be lost. What's odd is that CiviCRM is pretty responsive in general.

We're not using any payment processor.

Answer (score 1):

When debugging issues like this, experience says "round" numbers in a delayed request (like 120s for two minutes, or 300s for five) are indicative of hitting a timeout somewhere in the hosting stack.

This might for example be -

- a reverse DNS lookup that is failing (server lacks working DNS)
- an HTTP or SMTP request triggered within CiviCRM or custom code which fails after some time (eg: email is timing out, server can't connect to your analytics engine, POSTs make connection to a spam analytics tool which isn't responding, ...)
- "things like that ..."

Something is wrong here; that's not how CiviCRM works out of the box ([try it on a demo site](https://civicrm.org/demo)). But from the details here I can't tell you *what's* wrong.

Making specific guesses risks leading you astray even as it is likely to be of assistance. That said: You might want to check if this bug affects all situations where CiviCRM sends an email, or where CiviCRM processes a form submission.

This may require some debugging expertise I think - check out [civicrm.org/providers](https://civicrm.org/providers) if you don't have an existing team to lean on for this.

Do report back on the solution you find!

Comment: I see you have [a second question which refers to a 5 minute delay](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/11032/slow-to-open-at-first-daily-use) in another page. I hadn't seen that question when I wrote this answer mentioning "round" numbers like two and five minutes ... make of that what you will 

Answer (score 1):

It happens the culprit was the PDF receipt generated with the confirmation email. I disabled the PDF attachement in the confirmation mail (admin menu/system settings/ misc)

I saw there is a way to use an alternative PDF engine but since I don't really need the pdf, I simply disabled the feature

Thanks for the leads.